# How to write complex filter queries on M2M models in Django?

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework, many-to-many, m2m

I have an app matching candidates (`Candidate`) with jobs (`Job`).
For both of these models I have an m2m relationship with a Language. A language can be required for a specific job.

```
class JobLanguage(models.Model):

    language = models.ForeignKey(Language, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    job = models.ForeignKey(Job, related_name='languages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_mandatory = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And a candidate speaks a language with a certain level of "mastery".

```
class CandidateLanguage(models.Model):
    language = models.ForeignKey(CandidateComponentLanguage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    candidate = models.ForeignKey(Candidate, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='languages')
    mastery = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, choices=MasteryLevel.choices, null=True)
```

Now in my matching algorithm I need at some point to filter candidates based on the languages required for a specific job. Let's say I have list of mandatory languages for a job : `job_mandatory_languages_ids = [1, 2]`. How would you write in the most efficient way a method that only returns candidates who master (meaning `mastery=1`) at least all the languages in this list ? I would like to avoid having to iterate on each candidate to remove them from the list and just use something like `filter(Q())`

This obviously does not work but it is an idea of what I want to achieve.

```
def filter_on_languages(candidates, job_mandatory_languages_ids):
    return candidates.filter(languages__language__contains=job_mandatory_languages_ids, languages__language__mastery=1)
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

" I would like to avoid having to iterate on each candidate to remove them from the list and just use something like filter(Q())"

And what about doing a thing like this :

```
from django.db.models import Q

def filter_on_languages(candidates, job_mandatory_languages_ids):
    q_objects = Q()
    for language_id in job_mandatory_languages_ids:
        q_objects &= Q(languages__language__id=language_id, languages__mastery=1)
    return candidates.filter(q_objects)
```

This function takes a queryset of candidates and a list of mandatory language ids for a job, and returns a filtered queryset of candidates who master at least all the mandatory languages.

Like this you can filtered out your candidates without parsing them in a for loop.

Comment: Hi 1ronmat, thanks for your answer, that's an interesting direction but it is returning an empty queryset as soon as there is more than one element in `job_mandatory_languages_ids`, even if candidates do master it.

Comment: This iteration-on-languages approach works by adding a new `.filter()` for each new element in the list though. It's less elegant than having just one `Q()` at the end to filter only once but still better than iterating over candidates.